# PHP sessions and cookies question

Tags: php

Is PHP sessions the same as cookies? I ask this because I'm writing a privacy policy and the site uses PHP sessions, MySQL, JQuery and CSS. If Session are not the same should I change or leave the cookies name?

Here is what I have so far.

> Cookies - The Website uses "cookies," a technology that stores a small amount of information on a user's computer to permit the Website to recognize future visits using that computer. Cookies enhance the convenience and use of the Website. For example, the information provided through cookies is used to recognize you as a previous user of the Website (so you do not have to enter your personal information every time), offer personalized content and information for your use and otherwise facilitate your Website experience.

Comment: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/0/0

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions are stored, by default, in a temp directory on the webserver.  The session id is stored in a cookie called PHPSESSID.  By default, these are not tracking cookies and don't have to be persistent (e.g. they expire whenever you close your browser).  So they are safe to use even in websites that have enforced privacy regs.

For instance, I worked for a major branch of the U.S. military and we used _SESSION's all the time, despite the U.S. government forbidding a great many types of cookies.

To make a session cookie non-persistent:

```
// Make the session cookie last for 24 hours.
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored in the server, and after an previusly set ammount of time, it dies, or in other words, its deleted. Sessions do not need permission from the user to create, as a matter of fact, php initializes a session for each new web request that arrives from an ip to the server.

Cookies, on the other hand, are data stored in the browser's data folder, and every user needs to authorize the site to use them, and of course, they are not shared, meaning that IE and Firefox cannot share a cookie.

An example would be to login in this site and next time you point your browser it will remember your credentials, but if you try to open it with IE, it won't know who you are, hence the fact that they don't share data.

Hope it helps
Best of luck!